Find least squares system of linear equations
Find a real system of linear equations $Ax = b$ where A is 2 columns and 4 rows matrix and all elements of A are not zero, $b \in \mathbb{R}^4$, $z = (2\ 3)^T$ is the approximation of $Ax = b$ using least squares method and where: $\left|\left| b - Az \right|\right| = 13$
i.e. $A^TAz = A^Tb$.
I could theoretically calculate it by plugging some numbers, but this doesn't seem optimal.
Is there a way to effective calculate any such equation?
Thanks.

What if you take the columns of $A$ to be $(1/4)b+b_1$ and $(1/6)b+b_2$ where $b,b_1,b_2$ are mutually orthogonal? Then adjust $b_1,b_2$ to satisfy the criteria.

First pick $A$ and $b$ such that $Az=b$ and no cell of $A$ is zero.
Now, we try to add a vector $b'$ to $b$ such that $Az$ still is the best approximation, i.e. such that
$$
\arg\min_{z'}\| A(z+z')-b-b'\| = 0 
$$
The LHS simplifies to $\arg\min_{z'}\| Az'-b'\|$.
If the norm given is induced by a scalar product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$, then it suffices to find $b'$ that is orthogonal to the image of $A$, because then $\| Az'-b'\| = \| Az'\| + \| -b'\|\ge\| Az'\|  $. So all that's left is to scale $b'$ such that $\|b'\| = 13$.
Example with 2-norm:
We pick $A$ as simple as possible, e.g. $A=\pmatrix{1&1\\1&1\\1&1\\1&1}$, so $Az=(5,5,5,5)^T$.
Let $A_{\downarrow 1}$ be the first column of $A$.
Because $A$ has rank 1, we just need to choose $b'$ such that $b'^TA_{\downarrow 1}=0$, so e.g. $b' = (-1,-1,1,1)^T$.
Now set $\hat b := b+\frac{13}2 b'$, and we have $A^TAz = A^T\hat b$, $\|\hat b-Az\|=13$
